# Cannot Assign new value to Collection

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity-framework

I am having an extremely weird issue that doesn't make any sense to me. I am trying to assign a collection(col) to a property(PropertyEmployees), but it won't actually assign.
The property originally says "employee.PropertyEmployees = 'employee.PropertyEmployees' threw an exception of type 'System.ObjectDisposedException'", but it remains that way even after i attempt to assign a new collection on top of it.

The col collection contains valid data just before trying to use it.

The Account and Person properties have the same exception, but it goes away after i assign new objects to them.

```
 public IList<Employee> getEmployees(int landlordId, int propertyId)
    {
        try
        {
            IList<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>();
            IList<PropertyEmployee> propertyEmployees;
            if (propertyId != 0)
            {
                propertyEmployees = propertyEmployeeService.getPropertyEmployeesByPropertyId(propertyId);
                foreach (PropertyEmployee propertyEmployee in propertyEmployees)
                {
                    employees.Add(employeeService.getEmployeeByEmployeeId(propertyEmployee.employeeId));
                }
            }
            else
            {
                employees = employeeService.getEmployeesByLandlordId(landlordId);
            }

            foreach (Employee employee in employees)
            {
                Collection<PropertyEmployee> col = new Collection<PropertyEmployee>(propertyEmployeeService.getPropertyEmployeesByEmployeeId(employee.employeeId));
                employee.PropertyEmployees = col;
                employee.Person = personService.getPersonByPersonID(employee.personId);
                employee.Account = accountService.getAccountByAccountId(employee.accountId.GetValueOrDefault());        
            }

            return employees;
        }
        catch (ErrorHandler e)
        {
            throw e;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new ErrorHandler(e.Message);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the state of the `employee` object (or some other object accessed by the property setter) and has nothing to do with the value of the `col` collection or it's elements.

`System.ObjectDisposedException` is thrown when an operation is performed on disposed object. Hopefully, the `Employee` class contains a `IsDisposed` property that you can check before calling any `employee` members,

Comment: It works fine when it runs the code in the if. It doesn't work when it runs the code in the else even though both sections can potentially yield the exact same result inside employees.